# SQL get only items with all values in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have sql query like this:

```
SELECT m.id, 
e.id AS extraction_id, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY e.start_time DESC) as 
   start_date_rank,
e.end_time AS e_end_time, 
e.status AS e_status
FROM monitors m 
LEFT JOIN extractions e 
ON m.id = e.monitor_id 
WHERE m.is_deleted is FALSE
```

I am getting these rows:
[image]

My problem is, that I want only these ids, where in all e_end_time columns are timestams. For this example, it is only id 2. Can someone please help me, how to do it ?

Id 1 has timestamp, but only in first row. The second and third rows have null in e_end_time column, that is why it should not be returned.

Comment: PostgreSQL database

Comment: Shouldn't the result be ID 1 and 2 since they both have timestamps?

Comment: Because I want only ids where all e_end_time row have timestamp.

Comment: id 1 has timestamp value, are we missing something here or we looking at different images :)

Comment: Yes, id 1 has timestamp, but only in first row. The second and third rows have null in e_end_time column.

Comment: May I suggest you re-phrase that particular sentence then since it is not obvious that is what you want (your comment is perfectly clear though :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a NOT IN sub query to your WHERE clause

```
WHERE m.is_deleted is FALSE
  AND m.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT monitor_id 
                   FROM extractions
                   WHERE end_time IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to where clause should remove the id's which have null end times

```
and m.id not in (select id from monitors where e_end_time is null)
```

```
SELECT m.id, 
e.id AS extraction_id, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY e.start_time DESC) as 
   start_date_rank,
e.end_time AS e_end_time, 
e.status AS e_status
FROM monitors m 
LEFT JOIN extractions e 
ON m.id = e.monitor_id 
WHERE m.is_deleted is FALSE
and m.id not in (select id from monitors where e_end_time is null)
```

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way around, this will include to many rows in the result

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `group by`:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM monitors m LEFT JOIN
     extractions e 
     ON m.id = e.monitor_id 
WHERE m.is_deleted is FALSE
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(e.end_time);
```

Comment: And why would this be anonymously downvoted?  This seems to do exactly what the OP wants, which is to get all `id`s that have non-`NULL` values in `e.end_time`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.id, 
e.id AS extraction_id, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY e.start_time DESC) as 
   start_date_rank,
e.end_time AS e_end_time, 
e.status AS e_status
FROM monitors m 
LEFT JOIN extractions e 
ON m.id = e.monitor_id 
WHERE m.is_deleted is FALSE AND DATALENGTH(e.end_time)<>0
```

**The DATALENGTH() function returns the number of bytes used to represent an expression.**

DataLength is the best way solve your Problem because it also remove your blank Space...

**Thank You!!!**